# Java - Why does this Focus Traversal Policy not traversing on Text Areas/Combo Boxes?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextarea

I'm still learning about custom traversal policies and this really bugged me for hours already. Why won't it traverse over text areas? It only jumps over text fields.

So these are some components I added.

```
    Vector<Component> order = new Vector<Component>(11);
    order.add(txtfldBRN);
    order.add(txtfldName);
    order.add(cmbxDOBirth);
    order.add(txtfldBirthPlace);
    order.add(txtfldMother);
    order.add(txtfldFather);
    order.add(cmbxDOBaptism);
    order.add(txtfldMinister);
    order.add(txtAreaSponsors);
    order.add(txtAreaComments);
    order.add(btnSave);

    static MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy newPolicy = new MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(order);
    this.setFocusTraversalPolicy(newPolicy);
}

public static class MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy {
    Vector<Component> order;

    public MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(Vector<Component> order) {
        System.out.println(order.size());
        this.order = new Vector<Component>(order.size());
        this.order.addAll(order);
    }

    public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
            Component aComponent) {
        int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
        return order.get(idx);
    }

    public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
            Component aComponent) {
        int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
        if (idx < 0) {
            idx = order.size() - 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Before: "+idx);
        return order.get(idx);
    }

    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.get(0);
    }

    public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.lastElement();
    }

    public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTextArea` responds to the <tab> key, so it can insert tabs

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I added some more. Is it sufficient? I also got this Oracle example.

Comment: Can I compile your example?  Can I run your example? Make sure you take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand what it's we need from you before we can help you